# How to make expandable listview children scrollable?

Tags: xamarin.android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter, expandablerecyclerview

I've an expandable listview. I want to put different data in child views and make them scrollable. Currently my expandable listview is scrolling rather than child scroll. How can I restrict that and meet the requirement?

```
gridcustom layout:

    ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/item_Image"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:src="@color/accent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:text="Image"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_below="@+id/item_Image"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
    </LinearLayout>



my grid:


    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/container_scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp">

            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/gridview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:columnWidth="120dp"
                android:numColumns="auto_fit"
                android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
                android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"/>
        </LinearLayout>




Expandable listview adapter:


using System;
using Android.Widget;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Android.App;
using Android.Views;

namespace Sasken
{

    public class ExpandableListAdapter :BaseExpandableListAdapter
    {
        Activity _context;

        List<GridDataClass> _lstGrdData;
        ImageAdapter imageAdaptor;
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater;


        public ExpandableListAdapter (Activity context, List<GridDataClass> lstGridData)
        {
            this._context = context;
            this.layoutInflater = layoutInflater;

            this._lstGrdData = lstGridData;
        }

        public override Java.Lang.Object GetChild (int groupPosition, int childPosition)
        { 
            return true;
        }

        public override long GetChildId (int groupPosition, int childPosition)
        {
            return childPosition;
        }

        public override View GetChildView (int groupPosition, int childPosition, bool isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        { 
            //           string childText = (string) GetChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
            //          if (convertView == null) {
            //              convertView = _context.LayoutInflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.ListItemCustomLayout, null); 
            //          }
            //          TextView  txtListChild = (TextView) convertView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.lblListItem);
            //          txtListChild.Text=childText;

            View v = null;
            if (groupPosition == 0) {
                v = View.Inflate (_context, Resource.Layout.expandable_Child_Layout, null);
                GridView grid = (GridView)v.FindViewById (Resource.Id.gridview);
                grid.SetAdapter (new ImageAdapter (this._context, _lstGrdData));

            }
            if (groupPosition == 1) {
                v = View.Inflate (_context, Resource.Layout.expandable_child_1_layout, null);
                TextView txtView = (TextView)v.FindViewById (Resource.Id.lblListItem);
                txtView.Text = "Test";
                txtView.TextSize = 15f;
            }
            if (groupPosition == 2) {
                v = View.Inflate (_context, Resource.Layout.expandable_child_2_layout, null);
                TextView txtView = (TextView)v.FindViewById (Resource.Id.lblListItem);
                txtView.Text = "Test";
                txtView.TextSize = 15f;
            }

            v.Invalidate ();

            return v;
        }

        public override int GetChildrenCount (int groupPosition)
        { 
            return 1;
        }

        public override Java.Lang.Object GetGroup (int groupPosition)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public override int GroupCount {
            get {
                return 3;
            }
        }

        public override long GetGroupId (int groupPosition)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        public override View GetGroupView (int groupPosition, bool isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {


            View v = _context.LayoutInflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.HeaderCustomLayout, null); //infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);


            TextView lblListHeader = (TextView)v.FindViewById (Resource.Id.lblListHeader); 


            if (groupPosition == 0) {
                lblListHeader.Text = "QUICK ITEMS";
                lblListHeader.SetTypeface (null, Android.Graphics.TypefaceStyle.Bold);



            }
            if (groupPosition == 1) {
                lblListHeader.Text = "PRODUCT LOOKUP";
                lblListHeader.SetTypeface (null, Android.Graphics.TypefaceStyle.Bold);


            }
            if (groupPosition == 2) {
                lblListHeader.Text = "NON MARCHANDISE";
                lblListHeader.SetTypeface (null, Android.Graphics.TypefaceStyle.Bold);


            }
            if (groupPosition == 3) {
                lblListHeader.Text = "QUICK ITEMS";
                lblListHeader.SetTypeface (null, Android.Graphics.TypefaceStyle.Bold);


            }
            v.Invalidate ();
            return v;


        }

        public override bool HasStableIds {
            get {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public override bool IsChildSelectable (int groupPosition, int childPosition)
        {
            return true;
        }

        class ViewHolderItem :Java.Lang.Object
        {
        }
    }
}



Image custom adaptor::




using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

namespace Sasken
{
    [Activity (Label = "ImageAdaptor")]         
    public class ImageAdapter : BaseAdapter
    {
        Activity _context;
        List<GridDataClass> _lstGridData;
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView textView;

        public ImageAdapter (Activity c, List<GridDataClass> lstGridData)
        {
            _context = c;
            _lstGridData = lstGridData;
        }

        public override int Count {
            get { return _lstGridData.Count; }
        }

        public override Java.Lang.Object GetItem (int position)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public override long GetItemId (int position)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
        public override View GetView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {


            if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
                convertView = _context.LayoutInflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.GridCustomLayout, parent, false); 
                imageView = (ImageView)convertView.FindViewById (Resource.Id.item_Image);
                textView = (TextView)convertView.FindViewById (Resource.Id.item_name);

//              convertView.LayoutParameters = new GridView.LayoutParams (150,150);
//              //convertView.SetScale (ImageView.ScaleType.CenterCrop);
//              convertView.SetPadding (2, 2, 2, 2);
            } 

            imageView.SetImageResource (_lstGridData [position].intImgSource);
            textView.Text = (_lstGridData [position].strImgName);
            return convertView;
        }


    }


    public class GridDataClass
    {

        public GridDataClass (int item_value = 1, string item_name = "Temporary Id")
        {
            strImgName = item_name;
            intImgSource = item_value;
        }

        public string strImgName{ get; set; }

        public int intImgSource{ get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: Nesting scrollable Views is a **worst practice**

Comment: @BOb malooga  can  u suggest any alternative best practice?

Comment: Yes: **don't**. The standard behaviour is that only the ExpandableListView scrolls, not its individual groups. This is what the users expect it to behave.

Comment: As i understood the question is, ExpandableListView child item which is GridView is not showing all the item that is intended to be. restricted gridview height?